# jQuery adding dynamic data-title to links

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery. I'm looking to insert the content of a link into a span via jQuery.  I first targeted every link and wrapped the contents in a span by using `.wrapInner`, but now need to dynamically insert the data-title value to match each link.

```
<a href="http://samplesite.com">
 <span data-title="...."> Sample Link </span> 
</a>
```

In this case, I want span data-title="Sample Link", but I'd like it to change for every link. I target based on what the link text/content is.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?? Inserting the content of link means, are you going to show entire website referred in there?? What you need to get added in data-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('span').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).html());
});
```